# How to add row on last tr inside tbody with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new in JQuery and Javascript. And this is my code:

Javascript :

```
var newRow = '<tr>abc</tr>';
$('#itemTable tr:last').before(newRow);
```

HTML Code :

```
<table id='itemTable'>
<tbody>
<tr>zxcv</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>asdfghjk</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

If i use Javascript above the new row added inside  , but i want to add new row inside tbody before last tr. How to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: so select the tbody

Comment: `<tr>abc</tr>` is invalid markup.  you need `<td>` inside a row.  to target the <tbody> just add it to your selector: `$('#itemTable tbody tr:last').before(newRow);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to know the table structure [html Table](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_tbody)

1) find the body and append before the last one

```js
var newRow = '<tr><td>abc</td></tr>';
$('#itemTable tbody tr:last').before(newRow);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id='itemTable' border="2px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>zxcv</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>asdfghjk</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

So append it to the tbody

```
var newRow = '<tr><td>abc</td></tr>';
$('#itemTable tbody').append(newRow);
```

If you want it before the last row in the tbody, than select the last row in the tbody and insert before.

```
$('#itemTable tbody tr').last().before(newRow);
```

Comment: he says he wants it *before* the last row in the tbody - this won't do that.

Comment: @billynoah last tr is the tfoot (That is how I read the question)

Comment: ok - i guess it's a bit unclear and OP should clarify which "last <tr>" he means.

Answer (score 1):

You can check it this way:

```
$('#itemTable tbody tr:last').before(newRow);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `td` inside `tr` to contain actual value. Then target the last `tr` inside `tbody` and use `after()` like the following:

```js
var newRow = '<tr><td>abc</td></tr>';
 $('#itemTable tbody tr:last').after(newRow);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='itemTable'>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>zxcv</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr><td>asdfghjk</td></tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```js
var newRow = '<tr><td>abc</td></tr>';
$('#itemTable tbody tr:last').before(newRow);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='itemTable'>
<tbody>
<tr><td>aaa</td></tr>
<tr><td>CCC</td></tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
```